# Error on `node-gyp rebuild` on the `base64@2.1.0 install`

Tags: base64, npm, node-gyp

Running 'sudo npm install' on MAC, I got the error about `node-gyp rebuild` on the `base64@2.1.0 install`. Any way to resolve this problem? Please help.

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 69
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/jepeng/Documents/huron/wx2-admin-web-client/node_modules/base64
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.32
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 

npm ERR! base64@2.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the base64@2.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the base64 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls base64
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/jepeng/Documents/huron/wx2-admin-web-client
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Did you solve this error?  Same error (node v0.12.2, npm v2.7.4), os x yosemite

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by using older version of node v0.10.40

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue.
Followed the following steps to fix it on MacOS highSierra 10.13:

1. Downloaded command line tools (MacOS 10.13) for xcode and installed it. Download it from "https://developer.apple.com/download/more/"
2. Installed xcode 10.0 from the app store. Opened xcode and went through the regular configuration xcode does in the initial start up.
3. After this it started giving "xcode-select" path issue as stated in the description above. On running command "xcode-select --print-path" it was showing path as '/ Library/Developer/CommandLineTools', so i went ahead and tried "xcode-select --reset" after which the path changed to "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer". Immediately after it the build started working without any issues.